# File Not found Exception in Knownfolders.CamerRoll

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, image-loading, media-library

i am getting `File not found exception` when i try to load an image file using `KnownFolders.CameraRoll` property. The image is located in the CameraRoll of my windows phone 8. i have also enabled the following capabilities in my application

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
   <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
   <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
   <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
   <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
   <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
```

and here is my code to fetch the image.

```
 private async void cameraRoll_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs
 e) {
             try {
                 StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFileAsync("WP_20130607_003.jpg");
                 var mem = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                 BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();
                 bitImage.SetSource(mem.AsStream());
                 ImageView.Source = bitImage;
             }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }
         }
```

the image `WP_20130607_003.jpg` is also present in camera roll and i am deploying the app to the device. it raise exception on the `GetFileAsync` line. can any bode give me some hint that what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.cameraroll):

> Windows Phone 8:  This API is not intended to be used directly from
>   your code.

You can use the [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to let the user pick a photo. Alternatively, you can use [MediaLibrary.Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) to programmatically access the pictures. For example

```
MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
var picture = ml.Pictures.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("WP_20130607_003.jpg")).FirstOrDefault();
if(picture != null)  
{
   //get the image stream
   var picStream = picture.GetImage();

   //...
}
```